# LG G2 (d800) Stuck in Bootloop

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, boot-loop, lg-g2, lg

After rooting my new G2 and tinkering with some XPosed modules I am now stuck in horrible bootloop limbo. My phone starts, shows the LG splash screen, plays the AT&T startup sound, and starts the boot animation. The boot animation slows down and freezes after a few seconds, and after a few minutes the sound plays again and the animation starts over ad infinitum. I didn't bother installing a custom recovery like an idiot, factory reset doesn't seem to do anything, I can't adb in when I'm in download mode, and I can't find a stock KDZ for a d800.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try [flashing this zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2568891&d=1391958634) (the xposed disabler [attached to the OP](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053)) in recovery. You can also try repeatedly pressing any hardware button during boot until the phone starts vibrating. Xposed will have entered "safe mode" when it vibrates for a longer duration. From the post:

> Quick explanation of the safemode: It was developed by @Tungstwenty and makes it possible to disable Xposed by repeatedly pressing one of the hardware buttons during early startup. The phone will vibrate twice when the first key press has been detected. Then you have five seconds to press the same button four more times. Each key press will be confirmed with a short vibration; the final one with a long vibration. It creates /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/conf/disabled, which prevents most of Xposed’s actions (e.g. no hooks are made and no modules are loaded). There’s no 100% guarantee that this will get you out of a bootloop, but in most cases it should.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find the TOT file for reinstalling your firmware [here](http://storagecow.eu/index.php?dir=Xda%2FLG%20G2%2FStock%2FAT%26T%2F) for kitkat and the directions to install the TOT method [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2432476). You just have to scroll down half way and there is also a video and picture instructions.

Hope this works and be very carful!!

Comment: I have long since switched phones, but I appreciate the response and hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Hi, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Consider [edit]ing to summarize the content and/or expand the answer!